# Replacing this macro

Tags: c++, macros, template-meta-programming

Given this macro

```
#define MAKE_TYPE(_a, _b, _c, _d) ((_a) | ((_b) << 8) | ((_c) << 16) | ((_d) << 24))
```

I'd like to replace it so that it takes an *array[4]* instead.
So that I can write MAKE_TYPE("ABCD") instead of the ugly MAKE_TYPE('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

I'm using this in some at compile time to generate some constants.

But, it doesn't like me passing in a string like this

```
#define MAKE_TYPE(s) ((s[3]) | ((s[2]) << 8) | ((s[1]) << 16) | ((s[0]) << 24))
```

**error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression**

Well that didn't work.  So I thought I'd take a crack at it using template metaprogramming

```
template< char[4] s > class MAKE_TYPE
{
 public:
 enum{ RESULT = s[3] | (s[2] << 8) | (s[1] << 16) | (s[0] << 24) };
};
```

Unfortunately, this also didn't work.  I can't seem to put a char[4] in the template.
And I get these errors:

error: expected ‘>’ before ‘s’
error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression

How can I do it?

Comment: As others have said, you can't actually do this, but your error messages from the template version will be misleading because you've written `char[4] s` where you meant `char s[4]`. It still won't work with this fixed, but you'll get errors that tell you what the actual problem is rather than irrelevant syntax errors :-).

Comment: On top of the `char s[4]` thing, if you want to provide "ABCD" as a name, it should read `char s[5]` :)

Comment: yes of course, due to the null making it s[5].  Have decided to solve this a different way. thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means what it says: arrays can't appear in constant-expressions.

Template expressions must be constant-expressions, so arrays can't be in template arguments.

You could have a pointer to an array, but that's not what you want.

Ah, seeing as the limit is just four characters, you could use a multi-character constant, such as `'ABCD'` in single quotes. But, then the order of the characters is implementation-defined.

The other thing you appear to be attempting is to generate the name of the class itself from the character constants. This is kind of possible if you pass bare letters and not character literals into the macro, but, well, not really. Even if it kind of worked, it would be pretty hellish.

Comment: Thanks, I found an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried some more parentheses and/or casts?

```
#define MAKE_TYPE(s) (int((s)[3]) | (int((s)[2]) << 8) | (int((s)[1]) << 16) | (int((s)[0]) << 24))
```

This works for me, I use something very similar for FourCC codes and my macro is used by lots of different compilers.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it did what I wanted.  Turns out others are right. Cannot assign to a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the input is `char *`:

```
template <class RT> RT MakeType( const char * _arg )
{
  return _arg[3] | (_arg[2] << 8) | (_arg[1] << 16) | (_arg[0] << 24);
}
```

else:

```
template <class T, class RT> RT MakeType( const T &B0, const T &B1, const T &B2, const T &B3 )
{
  return B3 | (B2 << 8) | (B1 << 16) | (B0 << 24);
}
```

I would do:

```
inline unsigned int MakeType( const char * _arg )
{
  return _arg[3] | (_arg[2] << 8) | (_arg[1] << 16) | (_arg[0] << 24);
}
```

and cast if it is necessary.

Comment: This won't to do the computation at compile time. So the benefit of the macro is lost.

Comment: @xtofl: if you use references, the variable won't be copied.

Comment: @Naszta: I know.  But in this case, pushing the reference on the stack is four times more expensive than pushing the value... (on 32 bit.  On 64 bit, it may be 8 times.)  If you insist on passing the reference, do pass it const: the function is not allowed to change the actual arguments.

Comment: `inline` won't make any difference. By compile time comultation the value of the `RESULT` is computed at the time of compilation itself so that it behaves like a const value and there is no runtime overhead associated with it. Here making it `inline` *may* avoid the function call but the result is still computed at runtime.

Comment: @Naveen: no. The result will computed in runtime. More info on preprocessors: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node14.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi-character constant, e.g. `int four = 'four'`.  Behavior is compiler-specific though.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<(T('1234')==0x31323334), T>::type
make(T v)
{
    return v;
}

const int value = make('ABCD');
```

This is a safety net for the compiler-dependent behaviour of the multi-character constant.  You can add further implementations for different compiler behavior, switching bytes around as necessary.  This assumes byte-order of `'1234'` evaluation is consistent per compiler.

Template experts may be able to refine.